# If $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{d}$, then prove that $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(d^2+b^2+c^2)=(ab+bc+cd)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

It is given that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{d}$.

So how will I prove that $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(d^2+b^2+c^2)=(ab+bc+cd)^2$?

Comment: [This page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) contains information on how to properly type mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed. This feature doesn't work in mobiles.

Comment: But I does use $ $  around your mathematical expressions and use \frac{a}{b} for a/b. Use ^ for power. Is it what you need though?

Comment: Please confirm that the current way the problem reads is the correct way it should be written.  Whoever made the first edit had a fraction for the final line which would make the statement false.

Comment: @JMoravitz: You may want to edit the title, too.

Comment: See also: [Continued proportion implies $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2+d^2)=(ab+bc+cd)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44160).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $k=\frac{c}{d}$. Then $c=kd,b=k^2d,a=k^3d$. Now simply substitute and simplify.